# How to reload the captcha without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, laravel

This is my script code for captcha generation :

```
    var allValue = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y', 'Z','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0',];
    var cVal1 = allValue[Math.floor(Math.random()*allValue.length)];
    var cVal2 = allValue[Math.floor(Math.random()*allValue.length)];
    var cVal3 = allValue[Math.floor(Math.random()*allValue.length)];
    var cVal4 = allValue[Math.floor(Math.random()*allValue.length)];
    var cVal5 = allValue[Math.floor(Math.random()*allValue.length)];
    var cVal6 = allValue[Math.floor(Math.random()*allValue.length)];

    var cValue = cVal1+cVal2+cVal3+cVal4+cVal5+cVal6;
    captchaValue.innerHTML = cValue;
    thisValue = "";
    captcha_code.addEventListener('change',function(){
        thisValue = captcha_code.value;
    })

    submitBtn.addEventListener('click',function(){
        if(cValue == thisValue){
            alert('Valid');
        }else if(captcha_code.value == ""){
            alert('Invalid Captcha');
        }
    })
```

This is my html code for captcha inside the form :

```
<label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Captcha</label>
<div class="captcha">
 <div id="captchaValue"></div>
 <input type="text" name="captcha_code" class="form-control" id="captcha_code" placeholder="" />   
</div>
<a href="/">New Captcha</a>
```

How to get a new captcha every time I click on the 'New Captcha' button.

Comment: @Esszed done. After that?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the reload of the page by setting the href attribute to `href="javascript:;` Then putting the code that generates the new captcha into a function and calling it every time you click the link. You can create this by using event listener.

```js
 var allValue = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y', 'Z','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0',];


function newCaptcha() {
  var cVal1 = allValue[Math.floor(Math.random() * allValue.length)];
  var cVal2 = allValue[Math.floor(Math.random() * allValue.length)];
  var cVal3 = allValue[Math.floor(Math.random() * allValue.length)];
  var cVal4 = allValue[Math.floor(Math.random() * allValue.length)];
  var cVal5 = allValue[Math.floor(Math.random() * allValue.length)];
  var cVal6 = allValue[Math.floor(Math.random() * allValue.length)];
  var cValue = cVal1 + cVal2 + cVal3 + cVal4 + cVal5 + cVal6;
  captchaValue.innerHTML = cValue;
}
newCaptcha();

document.querySelector("#new_captcha").addEventListener("click", newCaptcha);

thisValue = "";
captcha_code.addEventListener("change", function () {
  thisValue = captcha_code.value;
});
```

```html
<label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Captcha</label>
<div class="captcha">
  <div id="captchaValue"></div>
  <input type="text" name="captcha_code" class="form-control" id="captcha_code" placeholder="" />
</div>
<a id="new_captcha" href="javascript:;" >New Captcha</a>
```